# Case Insensitive Core Data CONTAINS or BEGINSWITH contraint

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a predicate that looks like

`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"region=%@ && locality CONTAINS %@", self.region, query];`

I want it to match ignoring case. Whats the trick?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out I need to have a predicate in the form of:

`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"region=%@ && locality CONTAINS[cd] %@", self.region, query]`

and now it is case insensitive

Answer (score 99):

As described in the [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795), string comparisons in an `NSPredicate` can be made case insensitive by including a `[c]` (in square brackets) after the comparison operator (e.g. `BEGINSWITH[c]`). You can make the comparison diacritic insensitive using a `[d]` modifier or case and diacritic insensitive with a `[cd]` modifier. In your example, you would use:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"region=%@ && locality CONTAINS[cd] %@", self.region, query]
```

for case and diacritic insensitivity.

Comment: Awesome. I've been looking for this info a long time. Use BEGINSWITH though for faster response.